# Getting the font file Name/Location in FontDialog C#

Tags: c#, fonts, dialog, location, truetype

What i need to do is have the font file name (not Font Family name) after selecting a font in the FontDialog,
so that if i selected "Harlow Solid Semi" from the Dialog, i need to get the file name, which is "HARLOWSI.TTF"
so is it possible ? if not using the fontDialog, can it be done other way ?
Note: i need the user to see a sample text from the font before choosing it, so that listing the files in c:\windows\fonts directly will not solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.